# .NET Entity Framework code-first: navigation properties are not loaded

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my application I have many entities.

Two of them are Person and Company, which have a many-to-many relationship.

So in my code I have a Person class which contains a refeference to a collection of Companies (ICollection), and a Company class which contains a reference to a collection of people. (ICollection).

Using a first-code approach, the database was correctly generated.
There are three tables: People, Companies and PeopleCompanies.

In the table PeopleCompanies I have a record which should create an association between determined Person and an other determined Company, as shown in the image below.

http://s27.postimg.org/xnkz3j94j/DBPrint.png

So, what is my problem?

In my business logic I need to know which people are associated to a determined Company, but the navigation property of the class Company remains empty: ICollection.Count() -----> 0

In realty, as you can see in the image above, there is exactly one person associated to the company.

I need the navigation property!

Someone can help?

The code of the DbContext is below. Thanks!

```
 public class EnterpriseDataContext : DbContext
{
    public EnterpriseDataContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {

    }


    #region CRM Module

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyNote> CompanyNotes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lead> Leads { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonNote> PersonNotes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }

    #endregion



}
```

Comment: Can you please post the Person and Company classes, and the actual query you are using?

Comment: I'd also like to see the query you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers are telling me that lazy loading is enabled and you're not using the proper Includes.

First, you need to make sure you have the following using statement

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

And then use `.Include()` to load your people.

```
var myEnterpriseDataContext = new EnterpriseDataContext("insert connection string here");

myEnterpriseDataContext.Companies
    .Include(c => c.People)
    //.Rest Of Query
```

---

note:  you don't need includes for fields that you only access while executing your query.  I.E.

```
myEnterpriseDataContext.Companies
    .Select(c => new CompanyViewModel(){People = c.People});
```

Comment: I tried to disable lazy loading

_dataContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Nothing changed.

If I understood well you are suggesting something like this: return _dataContext.Companies.Include(element => element.People).Where(element => !element.Deleted)

(method: GetAllCompanies())

??

Comment: @ErroreFatale yeah.  Add that `.Include()` statement